# What do the 'k.A.' and 'n.b.' abbreviations mean?

Tags: abbreviation

What do the 'k.A.' and 'n.b.' abbreviations mean? It's used in place where numeric value is expected:

- weight: 10kg, size: k.A.
- weight: n.b., size: large
- ...

Comment: Lolx. I read the title & my first thought was "keine Ahnung" ;-)

Comment: Honestly, that's what I though it meant. But it did not match the official  "tone" of the surrounding text.

Comment: Würde mich wundern, im Umfeld englischer Vokabeln (weight, size, large) dt. Abk. zu finden. ;)

Comment: I tried to keep the question as English as possible ;D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"k. A." is the abbreviation of "keine Angabe" which can translated to "no specification" or "no information".

"n. b." means "nicht bekannt" or "not known".

Comment: "n. b." *can* also mean "nota bene", which is "please note" in English.

Comment: When it's not about numbers `k. A.` usually means `keine Ahnung` which is `no idea`.

Comment: English texts would often use "N/A" (not applicable) in such places, even though it is not exactly the same thing.

Comment: @raznagul `keine AHnung` is usually only the meaning in informal texts like short messages or chat.